# How to configure kile in texlive 2010?

Tags: texlive, kile

How to configure kile in texlive 2010?

Comment: Could you be more specific? Kile usually does a decent job configuring itself. Are you having problems installing Kile with TeXlive 2010 due to dependency issues? Or can Kile not find the path to your LaTeX binaries, or what?

Comment: appears to install kile texlive 2009.

Comment: Não se esqueça de colocar uma marca de seleção verde se você estiver satisfeito com a resposta dada.

Comment: @xport: writing Portuguese is not so nice for non-Portuguese readers of this English-language international site. To spare them the use of a translator: it means "Don't forget to put a green checkmark if you are satisfied with the answer." I guess. ;-)

Comment: @Stefan: OK. Next time will not do this again. :-)

Answer (score 4):

put the `.../texlive/bin/../` to your path and everything will be fine. A good idea is to create a file `zzz-texlive.sh` in `/etc/profile.d/`:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2010/bin/`uname -i`-linux:$PATH
export MANPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf/doc/man:$MANPATH
export INFOPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf/doc/info:$INFOPATH
unset TEXINPUTS
unset TEXMFCONFIG
```

replace 2010 with your current texlive year or change the whole path if you have another location of texlive.

Comment: Herbert, I could not. Permission denied.

Comment: @Regis: That had to be done as root. Alternetively put it into your local `.bashrc`

Comment: I'll explain: when I install it automatically install kile and texlive 2009. One solution would be to install the texlive 2010 and use the terminal.

Comment: I'm using texlive 2010 by the terminal, but every time I have to type
PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2010/bin/i386-linux:$PATH
explained by site http://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html
how do I not need to type it every time you use the texlive 2010?

Answer (score 3):

I just went through the painful process of getting TeXLive 2010 installed and getting it to work with Kile. Here are the steps I had to take:

- Uninstall Kile
- Uninstall all signs of `texlive` in synaptic
- Install TeXLive 2010 http://tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html
- Reinstall Kile from source http://kile.sourceforge.net/download.php
- Make it so I can run kile easily from the command line

  `alias kile='KDEDIRS=$HOME/kile-install:$KDEDIRS $HOME/kile-install/bin/kile'`
- And also change the path in /etc/environment (mine now reads:)

> PATH="/usr/local/texlive/2010/bin/x86_64-linux:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"

I also tried a few other things like changing paths and folder names in the process, but I don't think those affected it much.

Answer (score 2):

1. Edit the /etc/enviroment file as root and add the path directly,
   like:
   `sudo gedit /etc/enviroment`
2. then add the path, it should look something like this (if you distribution is 32 bit)

   ```
   PATH="/usr/local/texlive/2010/bin/i386-linux:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"
   ```
3. logout or reboot
4. next puge kile out of you system
   `sudo apt-get purge kile kbibtex` then
5. add this PPA   https://launchpad.net/~koshi/+archive/ppa
6. update and reinstall kile

P.S. Just one note, when you do a `sudo tlmgr update --all` it wont work. You just have to do a `sudo su` then  `tlmgr update --all`

Comment: Or do `sudo /usr/local/texlive/2010/bin/i386-linux/tlmgr update --self --all`. Btw, the recommended way to do `sudo` for GUI applications is `gksudo`.

Comment: I do not know how to install kile-2.1b5.tar.bz2 not know how to use cmake. I do not know and use the PPA.