# Setting the path to textlive installation, round 2

Tags: installing, texlive

It seems like everytime I install textlive distro on one of my computers I have the same problem:

```
peter@msideb:~$ tlmgr --gui
bash: tlmgr: command not found
```

The below reflects the current state of my .profile:

```
    # ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
# the files are located in the bash-doc package.

# the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
# for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
#umask 022

# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi

PATH=/home/peter/texlive/2011/bin/i386-linux:/home/peter/bin/:$PATH; export PATH
MANPATH=/home/peter/texlive/2011/texmf/doc/man:$MANPATH; export MANPATH
INFOPATH=/home/peter/texlive/2011/texmf/doc/info:$INFOPATH; export INFOPATH
```

My system: Deb 6 testing, 32 bit, xfce desktop environment.

And yes, I did log off after I edited the .profile file.

Yes, I appear to have the .bashrc file:

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return

# don't put duplicate lines in the history. See bash(1) for more options
# don't overwrite GNU Midnight Commander's setting of `ignorespace'.
HISTCONTROL=$HISTCONTROL${HISTCONTROL+:}ignoredups
# ... or force ignoredups and ignorespace
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
#[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "$debian_chroot" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    #alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    #alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    #alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# some more ls aliases
#alias ll='ls -l'
#alias la='ls -A'
#alias l='ls -CF'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ] && ! shopt -oq posix; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
fi
```

Comment: Isn't the usual install location would be `\usr/texbin`? If you type the PATH command into your shell manually, does `which tlmgr` find it?

Comment: I believe a similar question was answered in this forum [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8603/how-to-configure-kile-in-texlive-2010).  Although the question pertains to setting up KILE, you'll find that the answer with the most votes explains how to generically set up the path of TeXLive for all users.  See if that helps.

Comment: @Peter Grill:  How do you mean?  What should I type into my terminal to do what you propose?  Also I installed to `/home/peter/texlive/2011`, so isn't that going to be my path?

Comment: I was suggesting that you cut and paste the `PATH` command from your .profile into your command line and see if that sets the path correctly. If so, then you need to find out why the .profile is not being executed. If it doesn't result in the correct path, then you need to fix that path.

Comment: Can you run `$ echo $PATH` and post the result?  By the way, on the third line from the bottom of your `.profile`, you do not need to specifically include `/home/peter/bin` in your path, it should already be included by the conditional block immediately above that.

Comment: @Jan Hlavacek: `$ echo $PATH` gives: `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games`.  What does that tell you?

Comment: @Peter Grill: If I manually pased `PATH=/home/peter/texlive/2011/bin/i386-linux:$PATH; export PATH` into terminal and then run `tlmgr --gui`, it works!  So you  may be right, it isn't executing .profile for some reason.  What do I need to do now?

Comment: Looking at line 2 in the file, do you have one of the files `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bash_login`?

Comment: @Andrew Stacey: I have a number of similar sounding files such as .bashrc, .bash_history, .bash_logout in my /home/peter directory.  What do I need to do about this?

Comment: From what you say, it looks as though bash isn't reading this file.  I found http://freeunix.dyndns.org:8088/site2/howto/Bash.shtml which says that bash looks for `.bash_profile`, then `.bash_login`, and finally `.profile` and it loads **only one of these**.  Also, it only loads this on *login*.  It may be the case that logging in via X does not count as an actual login (see http://linuxgazette.net/161/okopnik.html) so this might never be read even if the other files aren't there.  Try putting the code in `.bashrc` instead.

Comment: @Andrew Stacey: I've tried restarting my computer with the PATH details inserted at the end of .bashrc and zzz-texlive.sh, with the path amended to my home directory where I installed texlive.  What should I do now...?

Comment: Give me a login on your computer so I can take a look ???  **Only joking!**.  Put in to *each* of the possible files the command `export BASHRCWASREAD="bashrc was read"` (with suitable changes).  Then log out, log in, and try `echo $BASHRCWASREAD` (and for each).  Also, take a look in `.xsession_errors` to see if there's anything obvious in there (maybe a syntax error in one of the files).  Try also `source .bashrc` (and the others) from the command line to see if there are any errors.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1311/discussion-between-andrew-stacey-and-ptrcao)

Answer (score 7):

Create as root a file named `zzz-texlive.sh` with the contents:

```
    export PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/i386-linux:$PATH
    export MANPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf/doc/man:$MANPATH
    export INFOPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf/doc/info:$INFOPATH
    unset TEXINPUTS
    unset TEXMFCONFIG
```

Change the `i386-linux` to your personal directory name.
Then save the file in the directory `/etc/profile.d/`. This script will be executed with every system start.

Finally, delete the lines in your `~/.bashrc` which sets any path for texlive.

Comment: Delete which lines in my .bashrc?

Comment: @ptrcao delete the lines about adding to the PATH.

Comment: @Raphink: I can't find any explicit reference to PATH in my .bashrc file.  See my original post for the contents of the file and please let me know what lines to remove.

Comment: @prtcao: well from your `~/.profile` then, or wherever else you've added anything related to the PATH.

Comment: @Raphink: Is there a way I can put the changes into effect without logging out?  I have a lot of windows open so it's a bit inconvenient to have to log out...

Comment: If you aim to build in a terminal, simply type `bash`. If you mean to use a dedicated program, I think it's easier to logout.

Comment: @Raphink + @ Herbert: I'm afraid it didn't work...  I did what Herbert said.  Ideas?

Comment: @ptrcao: where did you install TeXLive?

Comment: @ptrcao: in this case you should restart your computer and controll after log in the path setting

Comment: @Herbert: I've restarted my computer.  Can you please clarify what the "control after log in the path setting" part means I need to do?

Comment: @Raphink: I installed it to /home/peter

Comment: @ptrcao: then adapt @Herbert's answer with that path instead of `/usr/local/`

Comment: @Raphink: One step ahead of you.  Already tried that.  Three veterans on my case and we are still no closer...  :(

Comment: @ptrcao: run `echo $PATH` and it should show as first the /usr/local/texlive/...`

Comment: @Herbert: `/home/peter/texlive/2011/bin/unknown-linux:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games` - why does it say "unknown-linux"?  Is that normal?

Comment: Try `uname -m` instead of `uname -i`.  Test it on the command line first.  Actually, unless you're going to copy this from machine to machine, there's no reason not to just put in the `i386` explicitly.

Comment: @Andrew Stacey + @Raphink: So the solution is very particular.  Neither -i nor -m variant of the solution works.  It seems to only acknowledge the explicit `i386`.  I'm not sure why that is, perhaps you can rationalise it?  Does it have anything to do with the fact I'm using kernel 3 or Debian testing?  The other key thing is it reads .bashrc but not .profile or zzz-texlive.sh.

Comment: @Raphink + @Andrew Stacey:  By the way guys, I get different things when I use different options for `$uname`.  `peter@msideb:~$ echo $`uname -m`` gives `$i686`,
while `peter@msideb:~$ echo $`uname -i`` gives `$unknown`.  Neither of which correspond to what I thought my architecture was, namely i386!  How would we get the correct answer with `$uname`?

Comment: That may be because bash reads .bashrc every time an interactive shell is started, while it reads .profile only when it is a login shell and interactive shell at the same time, or when it is invoked with the `--login` option.  It seems that when you log in with your display manager, that does not happen.  It could be a bug or a configuration problem with your display manager.

Comment: I just add the path at the front of the PATH setting in `/etc/environment` and then log out and in again

Comment: Some quick googling found this: http://linuxgazette.net/161/okopnik.html .  I don't know how relevant it is today, but itt seems that `gdm` is seriously messed up, which does not surprise me.

Comment: @Jan: I found the same article!  (See my comments on the main question).  (Also see that I "continued this discussion in chat": http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1311/discussion-between-andrew-stacey-and-ptrcao )

Comment: @Jan Hlavacek: Not entirely sure but apparently Xdm is my display manager.  Does that tell you anything more?

Comment: @ptrcao Many, but not all, programs treat `i386` and `i686` as interchangeable names for the same architecture (Intel).

Comment: A late aside: some weeks later I got fed up with Debian's rough edges and switched to Kubuntu.  There I found it was sufficient to append the path details to .profile, even though .bashrc was present...  Not sure if this contradicts our earlier observations that .profile was being ignored in the presence of .bashrc...

Answer (score 7):

Mybe you can install TeXLive 2011 in `/usr/local/texlive`, and make symlinks for all the executables in `/usr/local/bin`.  That way you don't have to alter `$PATH`.

Comment: I cannot emphasize enough that *this* is the proper Unix-y way of adding programs that install to `/usr/local/<name>/<loads of directories here>/` to `$PATH`. Remember to make them soft links (`ln -s`) - it makes it much easier to tell what's going on when you later come back to `/usr/local/bin`

Comment: This seems to be the better way to do it. Would you be able to elaborate on this answer a bit by adding some steps?