# Cannot load font packages: cmbright.sty not found

Tags: fonts, packages

I have Ubuntu 10.04 and I have installed Tex Live 2011 (as super user) as per quick install guide. I also have run the command sudo texhash.

I use Texworks to make PDFs. But I get error when trying to load most basic font packages, like helvet or times. I use this command in the pre-amble of the tex document:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{times}
```

or any other name for font, like helvet or cmbright.

I get the error that the sty package cannot be loaded:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)
entering extended mode
(./letterToPresident.tex
LaTeX2e <2009/09/24>
Babel <v3.8l> and hyphenation patterns for english, usenglishmax, dumylang, noh
yphenation, loaded.
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/size11.clo))
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def))

! LaTeX Error: File `cmbright.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)
```

Is there any way to get a list of font packages THAT CAN BE LOADED using `\usepackage` command?

Comment: You seem to have a very basic TeX installation. Check with the package manager or do the big step and install [TeX Live 2011](http://www.tug.org/texlive)

Comment: Your log shows that TeXworks is picking up TeX Live 2009, installed by its package manager. Try running `tex -v` from the Terminal to see which TeX is being picked up, and if this is correct check your TeXworks preferences to make sure it's using the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks egreg and Joseph.

Apparently I forgot to add the Tex Live 2011 bin directory to the environment variable $PATH:

```
PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/i386-linux:$PATH
```

As a one-time fix it can be directly typed in the terminal. But it would be required again after every reboot (complained about here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32010/8613).

A permanent solution that automatically updates the path accordingly is shown here: [Setting the path to textlive installation, round 2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27922/setting-the-path-to-textlive-installation-round-2/27934#27934)

Now everything works!