# Biblatex styles won't be found

Tags: biblatex

In order to use a modified Biblatex style with MacTex, I copied the `.bbx` and `.cbx` files to `usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex-iest`. But when I try to use it in my document with `\usepackage[bibstyle=iest, citestyle=iest, isbn=false, backend=biber]{biblatex}`, it won't load it, but it produces errors like

```
Package biblatex Error: Style 'iest.bbx' not found. \RequireBibliographyStyle{\blx@bbxfile}
Package biblatex Error: Style 'iest.cbx' not found. \RequireCitationStyle{\blx@cbxfile}
Package xkeyval Error: `isbn' undefined in families `blx@opt@pre'. \blx@processoptions
Package biblatex Error: Command '\cite' undefined. \cite
...
```

I used my code on a Windows TexLive system, there it worked perfectly after adding the `.bbx` and `.cbx` files to the latex folder.

Now I found out that using ANY style in the `\usepackage[bibstyle=iest.bbx, citestyle=iest.cbx, isbn=false, backend=biber]{biblatex}` command turnes out not to be found!!
That means: The same errors happen when I change `bibstyle=iest, citestyle=iest` to `style=chicago` for example.

I'm missing somthing very important obviously. Please help my find out what it is!

Do i need to define any paths or something?

Here are parts of my code:

```
\documentclass[pagesize = auto, paper=a4, DIV=15,BCOR=0mm, fontsize=11pt]{scrreprt} 
\usepackage{todonotes}
\reversemarginpar
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\usepackage[bibstyle=iest, citestyle=iest, isbn=false, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\bibliography{Literatur.bib} 

\usepackage[]{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\AfterTOCHead{\singlespacing}
\KOMAoptions{DIV=last}


\begin{document}

\shorthandoff{"}

Text \cite{citekey1}.
\printbibliography 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Anyway, personal additions should not be in `…/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex-iest` but in `…/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/biblatex-iest`.

Comment: Do not copy the files into the `/usr` directory. You will have to refresh the file name database in some cases via `mktexlsr`. [Mac OS changes that affect lots of answers](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/6237/35864) might or might not have something to do with this. When you give the style names you do not have to (in fact, you must not) include the `.bbx`/`.cbx` file endings.

Comment: Please have a look at the [installation instructions on the `biblatex-iest` github page](https://github.com/Ekkehardt/biblatex-iest) which advises to copy the files to `~/Library/texmf/tex/latex/biblatex-iest/` on Mac OS X.

Comment: @moewe I don't think the changes to Mac OS can be involved in this, can they?

Comment: @cfr I don't know, I just read MacTeX and remembered these changes,and thought it might not hurt to mention that.

Comment: Were you able to identify the problem? Can you give us any more to work with?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem than Nik on Linux and can comment as follows: a) In contrast to the instructions given here (https://github.com/Ekkehardt/biblatex-iest) there is no folder ~/texmf/tex/latex/biblatex-iest/ below my home folder, in which I could put the two files iest.cbx and iest.bbx. b) Instead, I created (as root) a folder /biblatex-iest below the existing path /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/ and copied the two files there. REMARK: Downloading these files from the URL above will not work, as they are saved as html files! One has to create blank text files, copy the c

Comment: Is anybody here trying to use that style without knowing any german? In other words, do you guys need an english translation?

Comment: @Oli The two files `iest.cbx` and `iest.bbx` are completely new, hence *you* have to create a folder by that name. Do *not* do stuff as root when you don't know what they are doing. To the remark: You can download the complete zip folder, there is a button on the right.

Comment: @Johannes_B: Thanks for the link to http://www.freiesmagazin.de/ftp/2015/freiesMagazin-2015-08.pdf. The contents of the article by Frank Sandig are the same than in https://github.com/Ekkehardt/biblatex-iest. Help on german translation is not needed for me and I think that our "seagull" will probably not need that either... ;-)

Comment: @Oli The content of the article in Freiesmagazin is more detailed than what is said at github or in http://texwelt.de/blog/modifizieren-eines-biblatex-stils/. Trust me, i know ;-)

Comment: @Oli Now, it could be that you have to create the folder `~/texmf/tex/latex/biblatex-iest/` yourself. After you are done you probably also need to run `texhash` (see also [TeXLive won't find files in $HOME/texmf](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32167/35864)). Also downloading the files "raw" should work very well, they are not saved as  HTML then.

Comment: @Johannes_B That is an interesting article. Unfortunately in the `.bbx` version of the article there is a slight typo in the name format, it reads `\DeclareNameFormat{tubafshort}{}` and the following bibmacros are left dangling in mid-air. (The github version is fine, though in that regard.) The whole `tubafshort` semms not really necessary, as `firstinits=true` should do the same (except of course that the latter will also treat byeditors etc. the same way - which could be desirable or not).

Comment: @Johannes_B Of course, I forgot that then one needs `\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}` as well to get "Last, First" name order, sorry.

Comment: I didn't have access to a Mac recently but will try your suggestions in a few hours. Thanks so far!

Comment: @moewe: Manual creation of folder ~/texmf/tex/latex/biblatex-iest/ and putting the two files in there, followed by texhash as root gave remedy finally. Thanks a lot for this helpful hint!

Comment: @Oli Important remark: Though Stackexchange is a great place, stuff like that should go to the issue tracker directly on github. After all, this is a matter of installation and it is not ensured that the author of `biblatex-iest` sees this and is able to improve the installation guide. Right now, i made him aware.

Comment: @Nik The installation guide on github has been updated. Please see the comment above as well.

Comment: Any news here? This question has amassed quite a lot of comments, which eventually boil down to: Install the package as described in the installation instructions. The problem you are facing must lie with your installation and we can only guess what went wrong.

Comment: Finally good news for me, too! Following the updated installation guide worked perfectly.