# Texlive 2017 texhash not working

Tags: errors, texlive-2017

After I added some fonts to tex distribution I wanted to run texhash, unfortunately the error below is showing up. I installed texlive manually using ISO image of 2017 TexLive, I used `sudo` to install through `perl install-tl`, was that a mistake?

> texhash: /usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-config: directory not writable.
>   Skipping...
>   texhash: /usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist: directory not
>    writable. Skipping...
>   texhash: /usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-var: directory not writable. Skipping...
>   texhash: /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local: directory not writable. Skipping...
>   texhash: Done.

**Edit1:** I tried sudo but not working.

> usr~> sudo texhash
>   [sudo] password for usr:
>   sudo: texhash: command not found

**Edit2:**
Using `sudo -E texhash` is also giving error `sudo: texhash: command not found`

Comment: run it as superuser!

Comment: It is not working.

Comment: Looks like that the bin directory of TL is Not in your path. Does it work if you go first into the directory /use/texlive/2017/bin/.... and then run sudo ./texhash

Comment: I checked. It did work. But bin directory is in my path. All other latex commands are working. This is from my `.bashrc` `PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2017/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH; export PATH` bin is already in my path.

Comment: That is you path (bad idea to place this in bashrc, btw, th n the path may not work for programs you start from a menu), but that path is not the path used by the superuser

Comment: yo should set that path into `/etc/profile.d/` for Linux or MacOSX into `/etc/path.d/`

Comment: `sudo -E` will preserve the environment variables.

Comment: @Herbert I saw your answer here.
 https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27922/setting-the-path-to-textlive-installation-round-2/27934#27934 and used it. But still problem persists.

Comment: @yudai-nkt Your solution is giving same error which I have mentioned in Edit1 of my question.