# Make TeX Live on linux/mac system available

Tags: installing, texlive

I am currently giving a LaTeX course for students. Most linux users have TeX Live 2009 installed which is much too old, since I want to use `biblatex` and `biber`. If they install TeX Live from the website they can not access it because the PATH is not set up correctly.

I now found out that one can solve this by adding the PATH

```
PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/i386-linux:$PATH
```

to `.bashrc` and `.profile`. However I wonder if this could be configured for all users?

Furthermore I have a problem with the mac users. `pdflatex` starts from within TeXShop, but is not found from any other editor. We use TeXstudio for example. Any hint what could be wrong there?

Comment: see my answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8603/how-to-configure-kile-in-texlive-2010

Comment: Do you use MacTeX on the Mac? (http://www.tug.org/mactex/2011/) This is the modification of TeX Live for Mac.

Comment: @Herbert: Your answer at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27922/setting-the-path-to-textlive-installation-round-2/27934#27934 is better (the other answer has `uname -i` in it).

Comment: @Legolas: I have not mac, and I would have to ask the student, but i assume that mactex is installed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make that global, you have to configure it globally. As root, add the `PATH` statement either:

- to a file under `/etc/profile.d` (if that directory exists), as Herbert suggests, or
- to `/etc/profile`

This actually turns out to be a Unix question.

Comment: For OSX you should add the paths as a set of symlinks in /etc/paths.d and /etc/manpaths.d.  With *FreeBSD* and other Unices, you have to do something different again...

Comment: @CharlesStewart On the other hand, MacTeX does this during its installation.

Comment: @CharlesStewart The paths in `/etc/paths.d` aren't symbolic links.  They are just snippets of text that get appended to the main path. MacTeX creates the file `/usr/paths.d/TeX` which contains simply the string "/usr/texbin".

Comment: @Alan: Ah, it has been a long time since I messed about with that.  It is just the same as /etc/profile.d, except of course OSX has to be gratuitously different.  Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @egreg: I've use Texlive with Macs, not Mactex, because  I don't like the idea of having to learn a whole different file hierarchy and configuration behaviour to my Linux boxes.

Comment: @CharlesStewart There is *no* different file hierarchy: MacTeX installs TeX Live in `/usr/local/texlive/<year>` exactly like it's on Linux boxes (with manual installation) *and* it does automatic configuration for all users.

Comment: @egreg: Ah, then I should take a look.  What does "automatic configuration for all users" mean?

Comment: @CharlesStewart It means doing the proper additions to `PATH` and `MANPATH` that are accomplished in a different way than on GNU/Linux (Mac OS X is BSD-based).

Answer (score 1):

Since all machines run Unix/Linux, you can also do a shared NFS install: Install TL once on a server and share the installation via NFS. OpenSUSE has a package for that (`texlive-nfs`), TL2011 is somewhere in factory.

Comment: The university has no centralized server system for students and if I configure such a server it will be available within my institute, but not for the students. Anyway I would like to have something that works _on_ the computer of the students not only within the university network.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux I'd suggest to include the necessary paths to the `/etc/environment` file. You have to edit that file as root. Here is mine:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/x86_64-linux"
MANPATH="/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf/doc/man"
INFOPATH="/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf/doc/info"
```

Note that you'll may have problems updating TeX Live with tlmgr. Use the `env` command to change running environment for tlmgr. For example:

```
sudo env PATH="$PATH" tlmgr --gui
```

For the tlmgr GUI probably you'll have to install Perl/Tk.